# UITableView, How to fix footer so that it never moves up or down while scrolling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

UITableView, How to fix footer so that it never moves up or down while scrolling?
I've got only one single section in viewDidLoad I setup view for the footer:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"]];
```

but it moves up/down while scrolling, it there a way to get it fixed? thanks

please don't tell me to resize Table View for separated footer, because in split-view application you can't resize it(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a new subview and place it under your table.

Comment: in split-view application you can't resize it(((

Comment: you should be able to.  But if you can't figure out how to do that just put it over the table.  You could make it partially transparent or add an extra cell at the bottom so nothing critical is covered.

Comment: Just checked.  You can resize the table view.  You need to replace the provided table view with a normal UIView that has the table view as a subview.  Make sure to reconnect the outlets properly but you can make the contents of that view anything you want as long as there is a table view in there to connect to.  In fact you could get rid of the table entirely with a little bit of code re-working.

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
tableview.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: This only stops the bouncing. It will not stop tableview footer to scroll up or down with table content